# Contact form submitting twice to email

Tags: php, html, forms, header, double-submit-problem

I have a basic contact form that is sending the user's message twice to the company that has displayed the form: once with all of the correct info and once with the text fields blank, i.e. name, email, phone, message are listed but contain no information. I've been working on it for hours and cannot figure it out.

At the very top of my page I have this header:

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 if( $_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code'] &&  !empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) ) {
  // Processing
 header("Location:http://www.berrieswebdesign.com/business1 /thankyou.php?happymessage=thanks");
 unset($_SESSION['security_code']);

 } else {
 // Error Message
 header("Location:http://www.berrieswebdesign.com/business1 /thankyou.php?sadmessage=securitybreach");
    unset($_POST['submit']);

  }

  } else  {

  }
ob_flush();
 ?>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function(){
 $('#contact').validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
 $(form).ajaxSubmit({
 url: 'process.php',
 success: function() {
 $('#contact').hide();
 $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
 }
 });
 }
 });         
 });
```

and process.php

```
 function GetHeaders()
 {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: Company Name<info@companyname.com>' . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
 }
 // Get Data    
 $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
 $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

 // Send Message
    $headers = GetHeaders();
    $intro = "\"Thank you for contacting company name. We are very interested in assessing your situation and will be in touch as soon possible.\" <br />
    <br/>
    Best Regards,<br/>
    <br/>
    Company<br/>
    ";
 mail($email, "RE: Contact Form Submission", $intro, $headers);
 mail("me@yahoo.com", "Inquiry", "Name: {$name}\n Email: {$email}\n Phone: {$phone}\n Message: {$message}\n");

 ?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you try using only ONE mail() function. Each one sends an email...

Comment: Sure you're not calling it the first time you load the page (before any data input)?

Comment: its not because mail is called twice, one sends a reply message to the user (to confirm form submission)

Comment: Alfabrava- can you elaborate a bit? Not sure what you mean

Comment: If the user is only receiving one email(comment below), then the code you have above has no errors. Maybe you have another mail call elsewhere or something? To see if that is the case, try commenting the `// mail("me@yahoo.com"...` line out, and see if you still have a blank email.

Comment: ronalchn, the company receives no email when it is commented out or removed entirely.

Comment: I thought I had solved this issue by adding this change: mail($email, "RE: Contact Form Submission", $intro, $headers,
mail("companyemail@yahoo.com",  "Inquiry", "Name: {$name}\n Email: {$email}\n Phone: {$phone}\n Message: {$message}\n"));  But about a minute after submitting, I received the second blank email

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Based on the additional javascript code you added to your question...

The problem *could* be that the form is submitted by **both** javascript and the html. If you removed the javascript, the form may still submit. That indicates that javascript is not required to submit the form. However, if javascript is on, then ajaxSubmit will run, but that does not stop the form from submitting normally as well. If you want to stop the form from submitting, you need to say something like:

`return false;` on the submitHandler.

---

You could have that PHP code run whether or not a form has been submitted, and the code is on the same webpage as the form is on.

That would mean that an email is sent whenever the user first displays the form, as well as after the user submits the form.

To stop this, you can:

- make the form submit to a different webpage, and move the PHP code which sends the email to that webpage.
- Or you can set up an if guard, eg. `if ($name + $email + $phone + $message != "") { /* send mail here */}`. The `if (...)` condition checks if any data has been entered.

Comment: I removed the javascript and the form works, but still submits to the company twice-- I am editing the code above to show the header I have implemented for the captcha...maybe this is interfering or perhaps I can add the if/else statement to it?

Comment: I separated the two mail functions adding a message.php that is included in process.php. Still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls to your `mail` function. It should only be called once and look similar to this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Wrong! One of the mail calls sends it to the user, only one mail call sends it to company. It is NOT because there are two calls to the mail function.

Comment: Yes, one mail goes to user (they are receiving only one) and one to the company (they are receiving one blank and one completed).